# Twitter bootstrap v4: Vertically aligning breadcrumb element with navbar content

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, breadcrumbs, twitter-bootstrap-4

I have the below code snippet where in my navbar I have tried to include a breadcrumb with dropdown elements. I am trying to align the breadcrumb with the other elements of my navbar.

Please note: The below code snippet loads in mobile viewport which is fine - however, in `col-lg` and larger, the breadcrump element isn't vertically aligned with the other elements (i.e. `navbar-brand` and `form-inline`).

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-inverse bg-inverse fixed-top">
 <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarsExampleDefault" aria-controls="navbarsExampleDefault" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
  <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
 </button>
 <a class="navbar-brand py-0" href="#">EXAMPLE</a>

 <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExampleDefault">
  <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">

   <ol class="nav-item breadcrumb">
    <li class="nav-item py-0 breadcrumb-item nav-item py-0"><a href="#">Level 0</a></li>

    <li class="breadcrumb-item dropdown">
     <a class="breadcrumb-itemnav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="Level1Dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Level 1</a>
     <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="Level1Dropdown">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="http://www.example.com/Level1a">Level 1a</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="http://www.example.com/Level1b">Level 1b</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="http://www.example.com/Level1c">Level 1c</a>
     </div>
    </li>

    <li class="breadcrumb-item dropdown">
     <a class="breadcrumb-itemnav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="Level2Dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Level 2</a>
     <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="Level2Dropdown">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="http://www.example.com/Level2a">Level 2a</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="http://www.example.com/Level2b">Level 2b</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="http://www.example.com/Level2c">Level 2c</a>
     </div>
    </li>

    <li class="breadcrumb-item dropdown">
     <a class="breadcrumb-itemnav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="Level3Dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Level 3</a>
     <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="Level3Dropdown">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="http://www.example.com/Level3a">Level 3a</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="http://www.example.com/Level3b">Level 3b</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="http://www.example.com/Level3c">Level 3c</a>
     </div>
    </li>
   </ol>
        </ul>

        <li class="nav-item py-0 active"><a class="nav-link" href="http://www.example.com/Button1">Button1</a></li>
        <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
          <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search..." aria-label="Search">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
        <li class="nav-item py-0"><a class="nav-link" href="http://www.example.com/admin:index">Admin</a></li>
      </div>
</nav>
</body>
```

Comment: There are significant errors in your code (list items outside of lists, etc).  Have you accounted for those causing any issues?  In addition, is there a specific reason you're avoiding just STYLING Bootstrap's Navbar list instead of applying the whole of `.breadcrumb` to it?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the list items etc Robert - I've been trying to piece bits of bootstrap together and assumed its something I'm doing wrong - although I'm spinning my wheels and wanted to see if I'm wrestling with something that doesn't work with twitter bootstrap. Could you give me a nudge in the right direction on how I'd go about styling the navbar to get what I need instead of using `.breadcrumb`?

Comment: Are you asking to have your breadcrumb show similar in appearance to the search form field? Or are you looking to just align the text? Are you keeping the styling you have in your example or is it prone to change?What you are asking seems a little vague.

Comment: By the way you are using the Alpha version of BS and there is a newer version Beta /4.0.0-beta.2/

Comment: @crazymatt thanks - I've updated the question in the hope it's clearer (and thanks - I'll update my actual code to use beta 2!

Comment: You should just normal nav links for what you are doing. They also support dropdowns. See the documentation [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/#supported-content).

Comment: Thanks @Klooven - I'm trying to make it clear to users that each element is a nested subset of the 'parent' element to its left.  I'm guessing I was doing it wrong but the nav link elements were looking very separate and not obvious that they were associated with each other